# Fixing console output for my shell program

Tags: c++, shell, asynchronous

I'm writing a program that is designed to be a shell which calls receives input from the user and calls a child to execute the commands. The output of the program should include a shell prompt in the beginning of each line which displays the number of times a command has been issued, something like so:

```
bashell[1]: ls    
bashell  bashell.cpp  bashell.cpp~  myshell.c~
bashell[2]: ls
bashell  bashell.cpp  bashell.cpp~  myshell.c~
```

Unfortunately, I'm having serious trouble formatting my output so it looks nice like this. I think this might be due to the asynchronous nature of my program. I get something like this:

```
bashell[1]: ls
bashell[2]: 
bashell  bashell.cpp  bashell.cpp~  myshell.c~
ls
bashell[3]: 
bashell  bashell.cpp  bashell.cpp~  myshell.c~
ls
bashell[4]: 
bashell  bashell.cpp  bashell.cpp~  myshell.c~
ls
bashell[5]: 
bashell  bashell.cpp  bashell.cpp~  myshell.c~
```

ls is my input, the rest comes from the shell. As you can see the shell prompt doesn't even come up when I type in ls, it's just blank and the shell prompt comes up after I input the command.

This is the relevant code I have, I call printShellPrompt() to print the shell prompt before calling setup(inputBuffer,args,&background) to get the inputBuffer and command arguments.

```
int main(void)
{
    char inputBuffer[MAX_LINE];      /* buffer to hold the command entered */
    int background;              /* equals 1 if a command is followed by '&' */
    char *args[(MAX_LINE/2)+1];  /* command line (of 80) has max of 40 arguments */
    pid_t pid;

    // startup greeting
    cout << "Welcome to bashell. My pid is " << getpid() << "." << endl; 

    int commandCount = 1; // for counting the number of commands so far

    while (1){            /* Program terminates normally inside setup */
       background = 0;
      // printf("bashell[%d]: ", commandCount);
      // fflush(stdout); 
      // cout << "bashell[" << commandCount << "]: ";
      // cout.flush();
       printShellPrompt(commandCount);
       setup(inputBuffer,args,&background);       /* get next command */

       // if built-in command, handle internally
       if (strcmp(args[0], "whisper") == 0)
       {
         string whisperedPhrase;
         for (int i = 1; i < arrayCount(args); i++)
     {
           // change from uppercase to lowercase for each char in the token and concatenate
           // it to the final whispered phrase
           char letter = 'a';
       for (int f = 0; f < strlen(args[i]); f++)
           {
             letter = tolower(args[i][f]);
             whisperedPhrase.push_back(letter);
           }
           whisperedPhrase.push_back(' '); 
     }
         cout << whisperedPhrase;
         cout << endl;
       }
       else if (strcmp(args[0], "exit") == 0)
       {
         char command[] = "ps -p ";
         char pid[10];
         snprintf(pid, 10, "%d", (int)getpid());
         strcat(command, pid);
         strcat(command, " -o pid,ppid,pcpu,pmem,etime,user,command");
         system(command);
         exit(1); 
       }
       else
       {
         /*
         (1) if not, fork a child process using fork()
         (2) the child process will invoke execvp()
         (3) if background == 0, the parent will wait,
            otherwise returns to the setup() function. */

         // seperate filename and arguments given by user
         char *fileToRun = args[0];

         // fork a child process
         pid = fork();

         if (pid < 0)
         {
           cerr << "Fork failed";
       return 1;
         }
         else if (pid == 0) // child process
         { 
           cout << endl;
           execvp(fileToRun, args);
         }
         else if (pid > 0 && background == 1) // parent process
         {
           // parent will wait for child to complete
           wait();
         }
       }

      commandCount++; // increment the command count
    }
}
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This program is clearly C++ (not C).  Perhaps you should consider removing the [c] tag?

Comment: This is exactly how your output would look if you had `background` always set to true.

Comment: @n.m: well the shell should give the option to run the child in the background. If the user inputs something like "ls filename &" and ends it with '&', then this tells the parent to wait for the child process to finish, otherwise it doesn't wait.

Comment: Your convention is the opposire of what every other shell out there uses, but that's not important. How do you want your screen to look like in the no waiting case? Assume the external command takes 30 seconds to complete, and it prints output at the very beginning and the very end of its run.